# Best practices for rocket ascent trajectory guidance

Tags: orbital-mechanics, rockets, trajectory, guidance

I thought I would ask what the most used methods in industry are, in order to guide a launch vehicle into a desired circular orbit at engine cutoff. It seems that the use of direction collocation methods in combination with a non-linear programming approach are common means of calculating optimal ascent trajectories, although they seem to be computationally taxing and thus cannot be used in real-time. Another approach that seems to be mentioned often in the literature is the linear-tangent steering (LTS) law which is a near-optimal guidance law developed in the 1960s. So my question is: Is the LTS method still the approach that is most often used for ascent guidance, or are there "more optimal" methods that can be used in real-time. Furthermore, how close to optimal is the LTS law? The literature often mentions the assumptions used in its derivation, but I have not managed to find any comparison of how well it compares to truly optimal solutions.

Comment: What is the linear-tangent steering law? Could you add a link within the text of the question? See for example how [this question](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/14983/12102) did it. It seems central to the question. This would improve the question's value to others (including me) who don't already recognize the term. Other examples might include [this](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/643209.pdf) or [this](http://www.missionanalysis.org/campagnola/other/OptControlLecture.pdf) or [this](http://digitalcommons.usu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=3175&context=etd). Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

NASA Orion / SLS is still using PEG:

https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20150001961.pdf

Note that "linear tangent steering" is a provably optimal guidance law from calculus of variations.  It is going to be used in any finite-burn guidance program.  What you're probably asking is if PEG is being used--which is a predictor-corrector method that uses analytical approximations instead of integration of trajectories (e.g. using RKF45 or whatever), which is fast enough to be used closed-loop.

Also note that guidance programs like PEG are not used for the atmospheric part of ascent.  They're still used only used (AFAIK) exoatmospherically.

The ascent profiles for the in-atmosphere (endoatmospheric) are still calculated more laboriously on the ground.  And a lot of mission planning is still done from the ground in plugged into PEG using the "external delta-V" mode.  I don't know what is currently being used on the ground, in the late 60s it was the calculus of variations approach using runge-kutta integration and newton's method.

To confuse things slightly PEG's predictor could be replaced by discrete integration with Runge-Kutta which would improve accuracy and remove all the small-angle approximations and gravity integral approximations involved in PEG but at the expense of additional computation.  I don't know what the current state-of-the-art is with the predictor and the gravity integral calculations with PEG.